# Facebook thumbnail of my wordpress website disappear after a while. Any idea why?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, drupal, open-graph-protocol

I have a page with OpenGraph meta tags and when I first published the page it worked like a charm:

https://stargazerrock.com/stargazer-definition/

Now, after a few weeks, somehow my post does not show the image at all. (it shows a gray rectangle, though.)

The Facebook debug tool, here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

does show the image correctly.

This happens with many of my Wordpress & Drupal posts, which is problematic.

Remember what I said: at first it works. It's only after a while when I go back to my page that somehow the image is gone.

An example of such a post is this one (although I reposted in an attempt to fix the problem, but nothing got fixed, it's still missing the picture.)

https://www.facebook.com/StargazerRock/posts/1298528993624239

If it were just one post, I would ignore the problem, but now it's been like 10 posts that lost their image.

**Important Note:** I do my Facebook posting manually as I know that using a tool, or even just AddThis.com can create problems to the posts. That's also how I know that it worked the first time I posted. I also first use the debug too mentioned above to make sure I get a thumbnail.

As a side note: I noticed a similar problem on Twitter, but I've noticed that with many websites (not just mine) so I'm less worried about that one at the moment.

---

From 's answer, I see that the debugger uses a different CDN than the one used when I post:

```
https://external.fsnc1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php
  ?d=AQD6wD86Mtgq9AOg
  &w=540
  &h=282
  &url=https%3A%2F%2Fstargazerrock.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F11%2Fstar-gazers-on-fence.jpg
  &cfs=1
  &upscale=1
  &fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher
  &_nc_hash=AQBCV5QWsIV2g_q6

vs

https://external-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php
  ?d=AQARAAMY4iCsZ3kW
  &w=476
  &h=249
  &url=https%3A%2F%2Fstargazerrock.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F11%2Fstar-gazers-on-fence.jpg
  &cfs=1
  &upscale=1
  &fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher
  &_nc_hash=AQAeGBKWZLbtEZ8g
```

The main domain, the `d` and the `_nc_hash` parameters differ. The debugger is supposed to clear the cache, I'm wondering why would it miss that *other* server. But I would imagine that it's a bug at Facebook... unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I inspected your page

[image]

That image is an html `img` tag that points at an `https` url that stores your image.

```
<img class="scaledImageFitWidth img" src="https://external-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQARAAMY4iCsZ3kW&amp;w=476&amp;h=249&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fstargazerrock.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F11%2Fstar-gazers-on-fence.jpg&amp;cfs=1&amp;upscale=1&amp;fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&amp;_nc_hash=AQAeGBKWZLbtEZ8g" alt="" width="476" height="249">
```

This is your [`url`](https://external-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/safe_image.php?d=AQARAAMY4iCsZ3kW&w=476&h=249&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstargazerrock.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F11%2Fstar-gazers-on-fence.jpg&cfs=1&upscale=1&fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher&_nc_hash=AQAeGBKWZLbtEZ8g). It is not a static `.png` asset hosted on a cloud server (like AWS s3)

This is your host. fbcdn stands for Facebook cdn. Probably they are using this cdn to make sure that your link is safe

```
https://external-mxp1-1.xx.fbcdn.net
```

This is the query performed to your host to get that image. You can find it after the `?` sign in your url.

D could be the `id` of your image

```
d=AQARAAMY4iCsZ3kW
```

w stands for width in pixels

```
w=476
```

h stands for height

```
h=249
```

the url of your static asset. You are hosting it on https://stargazerrock.com

```
url=https%3A%2F%2Fstargazerrock.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F11%2Fstar-gazers-on-fence.jpg
```

some other params

```
cfs=1
```

size 1/1

```
upscale=1
```

fallback url

```
fallback=news_d_placeholder_publisher
```

irrelevant parameters

```
_nc_hash=AQAeGBKWZLbtEZ8g
```

This is the image url you are pointing to

https://stargazerrock.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/star-gazers-on-fence.jpg

You can avoid this issue by uploading your picture to facebook.

Comment: The static URL works just fine, though. I downloaded that HTML page and tried to open it on my computer, it shows me the Facebook front page with a message "Please upgrade your browser".

Comment: Note that a CDN (Content Delivery Network) is similar to a cache that's available worldwide. I knew that they would take my image and save it in their cache. What I'm wondering is how the heck could they end up with their home page instead of my image in there!

Comment: @AlexisWilke I believe you are confused.